# Does using an instance of a class inside of another class count as dependency or association?

Tags: java, class, dependencies, uml, associations

I’m having a hard time figuring out whether instantiating a class inside of another and then using some of its methods counts as dependency or association within UML class diagrams. For example:

```
public class Example {
    Thing thing = new Thing();

    public void method() {
            thing.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Is this association because Example "has a" Thing? Or is this dependency because Example has a method that "uses" Thing to work properly?

Comment: Describing this as "instantiating a class inside another class" is not very precise. The case you show in your code is that a class contains an instance of another class, which is not implied by instantiating an instance.

Comment: My bad, fixed the title so that it should be more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UML, you would represent this with an **association** between `Example` and `Thing`:

- Purists would suggest the [dot notation](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf) and put a tiny dot on the `Thing` end: this tells that `Example` owns the end of the association. Not all the modelling tools support this notation.
- Since the instance of `Example` would always know the instance of `Thing` but probably not the opposite, you'd want to show this association navigable (open arrow at the end).

The association implies the dependency.  So you should not add a redundant dependency to the diagram. A dependency without association would look like:

```
public class Example {
    Thing thing = new Thing();             // Example is associated to Thing

    public void method(AnotherThing x) {   // Example depends on AnotherThing
            ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be considered a dependency if we instead created an instance of Thing inside of the method? If I understand correctly, it would mean that “thing” will instead become a local variable, and the Example class will only know about it when the method is used. Am I correct in this?

Comment: @PlzEnjoyGame If `thing` is a field of hte example class, whether you create it or not, would be shown as an association: class diagrams show the structure and not the dynamic behavior.  But if you would not have a `Thing` field in the class, and nevertheless use a `Thing` as parameter, or local variable, or return a Thing, you would have a dependency (a «Create» dependency if the class creates them).